# How to access a variable from within an inner function in react/redux actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Within my getUnaddedCartItems() function I call loadCartItems() but I need access to the const addedItems within the .then() function.  This all happens within my cart actions js file.  Can someone please tell me how I can have access to an outer variable within an inner function?

```
export function loadCartItems() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({
            type: types.LOAD_CART_PRODUCTS
        });
        return AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY_JWT_TOKEN).then((key) => {
            return API.getCartItems(key)
                .then((response) => {
                    return dispatch({
                        type: types.LOAD_CART_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
                        response
                    });
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error retrieving cart products');
                })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Error retrieving cart items from local storage");
        });
    };
}



export function getUnaddedCartItems() {
        return (dispatch, getState) => {
            dispatch({
                type: types.GET_UNADDED_ITEMS
            });        
            return AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY_CART_ITEMS).then((result) => {
                const addedItems = JSON.parse(result);

                loadCartItems()(dispatch, getState).then((result) => {
                    const cartItems = result.response.products;

                    const unaddedCartItems = addedItems.filter((addedItem) => {
                        return cartItems.find(cartItem => cartItem.id !== addedItem.productId);
                    });

                    return unaddedCartItems;
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log('error: ', err);
                });
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log('error: ', error);
            });
        };
    }
```

Comment: The inner functions always have access to variables in the outer function. What you have done should work.

Comment: addedItems is declared within the AsyncStorage call but is being used in my filter method within the loadCartItems function.  However, it doesn't know what addedItems is so I get an error.  Are you sure it looks good??  Could it be because its being used within a .then()?

Comment: Can you show the code for your `loadCartItems` function?

Comment: Ok I have included it now.

Comment: I would highly recommend reading up on closures and variable scopes in javascript. Most of javascripts power comes from using closures as a state (variables) sharing mechanism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `return` keyword at the beginning of the line

```
return AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY_CART_ITEMS).then((result) => {
```

That might be preventing your inner function from running, if it ends the execution too early.

Also, I see you call

```
dispatch({
    type: types.GET_UNADDED_ITEMS
});
```

at the beginning of the function,

but nowhere else are you dispatching an action afterwards. I think you need dispatch the appropriate action instead of `return unaddedCartItems` at the end of the inner `then()`

**Update**

Replacing

```
loadCartItems()(dispatch, getState).then((result) => {
    const cartItems = result.response.products;

    const unaddedCartItems = addedItems.filter((addedItem) => {
        return cartItems.find(cartItem => cartItem.id !== addedItem.productId);
    });

    return unaddedCartItems;
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('error: ', err);
});
```

With `dispatch(loadCartItems())` may help achieve the desired outcome. Calling it without `dispatch` does not connect it to the redux store, which you are using inside the inner `.then` of `loadCartItems`

Comment: I put a return in front of the AsyncStorage.getItem() call because in my component I attached a .then() call to the getUnaddedCartItems() function.  Also, I don't have any other action to call so that is why I am simply returning unaddedCartItems because in my component I'm just expecting data to be returned.